# бургер при адаптивной навигации на бутстрапе раздвигает хедер по высоте

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, меню, навигация

при клике на button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" срабатывает раскрытие скрытого меню, но во-первых раскрывается меню узко(не по всеё ширине экрана), а во-вторых - само раскрывающееся меню раздвигает своими li-шками хэдэр по высоте. Подскажите, пжл., в чём может быть причина?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приложи код

Comment: <nav class="navbar"><div class="navbar-header"> <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="sr-only">{{ trans('common.toggle_navigation') }}</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dprc1c  -  вот так раздвигает по вертикали хэдэр и сам "navbar-collapse collapse" узкий

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: пример работает, а в проекте - нет(. ну в подходе тяжело запутаться(((

Comment: @ВладиславКураев вот сюда `<nav class="navbar">` добавьте еще класс `navbar-default`

Comment: добавлял уже(...не помогает

Comment: @ВладиславКураев скинь нормальный код, тогда помогу, а еще лучше приложи его к своему посту, то, что ты скинул это какая то лажа.

Comment: код, который я приложил - из шаблона ларавэла...увидел с Вашего примера, что навигация тоже раздвигает хэдэр по вертикали; - такой подход на всех источниках, что я находил. Надо чтобы меню выпадало сверху вниз как на абсолюте и не подвигало вниз контент.